# Result of RapidMiner model -> input to Execute R Script

Tags: r, machine-learning, execute, rapidminer

I am very sorry if it is a wrong place to post a question on rapid miner . I am just posting to try my luck to get an answer.

I am new to rapidminer, I was able to implement a couple of R models(C5,rpart) in rapid miner successfully. Now I am trying to use the result of rapid miner model (Decision Tree) as input to R script , I am getting the below error :

> "Incompatible data (Decision Tree) delivered at port input 1. The
>   data delivered at the specified port was of the wrong type."

Unable to find a way to read the output of Rapidminer as input to R-script.
What I am trying to achieve:
I want to create a new field in the final output that explains in text how a data point was predicted as 0 or 1 (Binary -Decision Tree)

Example: if my model takes three variables a,b,c had the below conditions:

> a>10     b<5 :1 {1=6,0=0} c<5 :0 {1=0,0=3}

So in my final dataset it should have created a column for all 1's with text "a>10 & b<5" and all 0 as "C<5"
My Execute R script will have 2 inputs 
1)Model (which has the conditions) 
2)Test dataset+predictions (on which the text variable has to be created)

Any help/tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The output _exa_ port of a decision tree operator could - in theory - be the input of execute R script. There, you can add a column to the data frame depending on the label.

Answer (score 2):

The R-Script Operator excepts either a RapidMiner ExampleSet or a R object, that's why you get an error.
You could use the "Decision Tree to Example Set" from the [Converters Extension](https://marketplace.rapidminer.com/UpdateServer/faces/product_details.xhtml?productId=rmx_converters%22Converters%20Extension%22) to get the set of rules in the decision tree as an ExampleSet.

Otherwise, if you want to apply your decision tree model, just use the "Apply Model" Operator in RapidMiner, then you get a new column with the predicted label, as well as an confidence value for this prediction.

Comment: Hi David,
Thanks for your reply.I just installed the extension "Converter Extension" it doesn't seem to have "Decison Tree to Example Set"
it only has the below options :

Model:
- Kernel Model to ExampleSet
- Association Rules to ExampleSet
- Linear Regression Model to ExampleSet
Preprocessing Model
- PCA Result to ExampleSet
- Normalization to ExampleSet
Performance:
- ROC Curve to ExampleSet
Examples:
- ExampleSet to HTML
Matrix:
- Matrix to ExampleSet
Parameters:
- Parameter Set to ExampleSet

Comment: Oh you are right. This Operator is not yet released, but in another Extension called [Operator Toolbox](https://marketplace.rapidminer.com/UpdateServer/faces/product_details.xhtml?productId=rmx_operator_toolbox)  there is an Operator called "Get Decision Tree Path", which returns to a given example set exactly the traversed path in the decision tree model.

Comment: Perfect Thanks :)